# UNIX file change interval

Tags: shell, unix

Is there a way to determine change frequency of a file?

The situation is i have a log file which will be rolling all the time, in that way i can say my application is running .

if it's not writing any then i can say there's some problem.
So instead of using tail and see manually if the logs are rolling , how can i check if the log is rolling programmatically like analysing it for 2 mins and checking if logs are being written?
Is there a way to track the change interval by using stat in some program kinda ???

i mean i can take 2 mins as parameter,at first storing mtime and after 2mins checking with new time and confirming it's changed, but i need to know the frequency kinda like x modifications/time or number.of.lines written/sec kinda

Answer (score 1):

A better idea would be to have inotify, gamin, or FAM notify you when the file has been modified.

Comment: instead of using those inotify etc .,tools, will it done using common unix utilities?

Comment: Sure, I suppose. But this isn't really the place to ask about those.

Answer (score 1):

On a Unix system, the `stat()` family of functions will obtain a file's metadata. The `st_mtime` member of the `struct stat` structure will give you the time of last modification.

Also on a Unix system, sending a signal `0` to a process will tell you if the process is still alive without affecting the process.